# BSP dungeon generation is not generating corridors

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, procedural-generation, space-partitioning

I'm making a 2D RPG for my graduation project, and I'm at the point where I want to generate my dungeons randomly.
I'm following this tutorial http://www.rombdn.com/blog/2018/01/12/random-dungeon-bsp-unity/ to make a randomly generated dungeon.

After tons of research, I've found that the BSP algorithm generates the dungeon design I desire for my game. I've followed the tutorial provided in the link, step by step. I provided my script for you to see it:

```
public class BoardManager : MonoBehaviour {
    public GameObject floorTile;
    public GameObject corridorTile;

public int boardRows, boardColumns;
public int minRoomSize, maxRoomSize;

private GameObject[,] boardPositionsFloor;

public class SubDungeon {

    public SubDungeon left, right;
    public Rect rect;
    public Rect room = new Rect(-1,-1, 0, 0); // i.e null
    public int debugId;

    private static int debugCounter = 0;

    public List<Rect> corridors = new List<Rect>();

    public SubDungeon(Rect mrect) {
        rect = mrect;
        debugId = debugCounter;
        debugCounter++;
    }

    public bool IAmLeaf() {
        return left == null && right == null;
    }

    public bool Split(int minRoomSize, int maxRoomSize) {
        if (!IAmLeaf()) {
            return false;
        }

        // choose a vertical or horizontal split depending on the proportions
        // i.e. if too wide split vertically, or too long horizontally,
        // or if nearly square choose vertical or horizontal at random
        bool splitH;
        if (rect.width / rect.height >= 1.25) {
            splitH = false;
        } else if (rect.height / rect.width >= 1.25) {
            splitH = true;
        } else {
            splitH = Random.Range (0.0f, 1.0f) > 0.5;
        }

        if (Mathf.Min(rect.height, rect.width) / 2 < minRoomSize) {
            Debug.Log ("Sub-dungeon " + debugId + " will be a leaf");
            return false;
        }

        if (splitH) {
            // split so that the resulting sub-dungeons widths are not too small
            // (since we are splitting horizontally)
            int split = Random.Range (minRoomSize, (int)(rect.width - minRoomSize));

            left = new SubDungeon (new Rect (rect.x, rect.y, rect.width, split));
            right = new SubDungeon (
                new Rect (rect.x, rect.y + split, rect.width, rect.height - split));
        }
        else {
            int split = Random.Range (minRoomSize, (int)(rect.height - minRoomSize));

            left = new SubDungeon (new Rect (rect.x, rect.y, split, rect.height));
            right = new SubDungeon (
                new Rect (rect.x + split, rect.y, rect.width - split, rect.height));
        }

        return true;
    }

    public void CreateRoom() {
        if (left != null) {
            left.CreateRoom ();
        }
        if (right != null) {
            right.CreateRoom ();
        }
        if (IAmLeaf()) {
            int roomWidth = (int)Random.Range (rect.width / 2, rect.width - 2);
            int roomHeight = (int)Random.Range (rect.height / 2, rect.height - 2);
            int roomX = (int)Random.Range (1, rect.width - roomWidth - 1);
            int roomY = (int)Random.Range (1, rect.height - roomHeight - 1);

            // room position will be absolute in the board, not relative to the sub-dungeon
            room = new Rect (rect.x + roomX, rect.y + roomY, roomWidth, roomHeight);
            Debug.Log ("Created room " + room + " in sub-dungeon " + debugId + " " + rect);
        }
    }

    public Rect GetRoom() {
        if (IAmLeaf()) {
            return room;
        }
        if (left != null) {
            Rect lroom = left.GetRoom ();
            if (lroom.x != -1) {
                return lroom;
            }
        }
        if (right != null) {
            Rect rroom = right.GetRoom ();
            if (rroom.x != -1) {
                return rroom;
            }
        }

        // workaround non nullable structs
        return new Rect (-1, -1, 0, 0);
    }

    public void CreateCorridorBetween(SubDungeon left, SubDungeon right) {
        Rect lroom = left.GetRoom ();
        Rect rroom = right.GetRoom ();

        Debug.Log("Creating corridor(s) between " + left.debugId + "(" + lroom + ") and " + right.debugId + " (" + rroom + ")");
        Debug.Log ("hello");
        // attach the corridor to a random point in each room
        Vector2 lpoint = new Vector2 ((int)Random.Range (lroom.x + 1, lroom.xMax - 1), (int)Random.Range (lroom.y + 1, lroom.yMax - 1));
        Vector2 rpoint = new Vector2 ((int)Random.Range (rroom.x + 1, rroom.xMax - 1), (int)Random.Range (rroom.y + 1, rroom.yMax - 1));

        // always be sure that left point is on the left to simplify the code
        if (lpoint.x > rpoint.x) {
            Vector2 temp = lpoint;
            lpoint = rpoint;
            rpoint = temp;
        }

        int w = (int)(lpoint.x - rpoint.x);
        int h = (int)(lpoint.y - rpoint.y);

        Debug.Log ("lpoint: " + lpoint + ", rpoint: " + rpoint + ", w: " + w + ", h: " + h);

        // if the points are not aligned horizontally
        if (w != 0) {
            // choose at random to go horizontal then vertical or the opposite
            if (Random.Range (0, 1) > 2) {
                // add a corridor to the right
                corridors.Add (new Rect (lpoint.x, lpoint.y, Mathf.Abs (w) + 1, 1));

                // if left point is below right point go up
                // otherwise go down
                if (h < 0) {
                    corridors.Add (new Rect (rpoint.x, lpoint.y, 1, Mathf.Abs (h)));
                } else {
                    corridors.Add (new Rect (rpoint.x, lpoint.y, 1, -Mathf.Abs (h)));
                }
            } else {
                // go up or down
                if (h < 0) {
                    corridors.Add (new Rect (lpoint.x, lpoint.y, 1, Mathf.Abs (h)));
                } else {
                    corridors.Add (new Rect (lpoint.x, rpoint.y, 1, Mathf.Abs (h)));
                }

                // then go right
                corridors.Add (new Rect (lpoint.x, rpoint.y, Mathf.Abs (w) + 1, 1));
            }
        } else {
            // if the points are aligned horizontally
            // go up or down depending on the positions
            if (h < 0) {
                corridors.Add (new Rect ((int)lpoint.x, (int)lpoint.y, 1, Mathf.Abs (h)));
            } else {
                corridors.Add (new Rect ((int)rpoint.x, (int)rpoint.y, 1, Mathf.Abs (h)));
            }
        }

        Debug.Log ("Corridors: ");
        foreach (Rect corridor in corridors) {
            Debug.Log ("corridor: " + corridor);
        }
    }
}

public void CreateBSP(SubDungeon subDungeon) {
    Debug.Log ("Splitting sub-dungeon " + subDungeon.debugId + ": " + subDungeon.rect);
    if (subDungeon.IAmLeaf()) {
        // if the sub-dungeon is too large
        if (subDungeon.rect.width > maxRoomSize
            || subDungeon.rect.height > maxRoomSize
            || Random.Range(0.0f,1.0f) > 0.25) {

            if (subDungeon.Split (minRoomSize, maxRoomSize)) {
                Debug.Log ("Splitted sub-dungeon " + subDungeon.debugId + " in "
                    + subDungeon.left.debugId + ": " + subDungeon.left.rect + ", "
                    + subDungeon.right.debugId + ": " + subDungeon.right.rect);

                CreateBSP(subDungeon.left);
                CreateBSP(subDungeon.right);
            }
        }
    }
}
public void DrawRooms(SubDungeon subDungeon) {
    if (subDungeon == null) {
        return;
    }
    if (subDungeon.IAmLeaf()) {
        for (int i = (int)subDungeon.room.x; i < subDungeon.room.xMax; i++) {
            for (int j = (int)subDungeon.room.y; j < subDungeon.room.yMax; j++) {
                GameObject instance = Instantiate (floorTile, new Vector3 (i, j, 0f), Quaternion.identity) as GameObject;
                instance.transform.SetParent (transform);
                boardPositionsFloor [i, j] = instance;
            }
        }
    } else {
        DrawRooms (subDungeon.left);
        DrawRooms (subDungeon.right);
    }
}

void DrawCorridors(SubDungeon subDungeon) {
    if (subDungeon == null) {
        return;
    }

    DrawCorridors (subDungeon.left);
    DrawCorridors (subDungeon.right);

    foreach (Rect corridor in subDungeon.corridors) {
        for (int i = (int)corridor.x; i < corridor.xMax; i++) {
            for (int j = (int)corridor.y; j < corridor.yMax; j++) {
                if (boardPositionsFloor [i, j] == null) {
                    GameObject instance = Instantiate (corridorTile, new Vector3 (i, j, 0f), Quaternion.identity) as GameObject;
                    instance.transform.SetParent (transform);
                    boardPositionsFloor [i, j] = instance;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

void Start () {
    SubDungeon rootSubDungeon = new SubDungeon (new Rect (0, 0, boardRows, boardColumns));
    CreateBSP (rootSubDungeon);
    rootSubDungeon.CreateRoom ();

    boardPositionsFloor = new GameObject[boardRows, boardColumns];
    DrawCorridors (rootSubDungeon);
    DrawRooms (rootSubDungeon);
}
}
```

The rooms are being created perfectly and there are no error messages. I've noticed that the CreateCorridorBetween isn't being called from anywhere, even on the author's blog; therefore, the corridors aren't being created. How do I call it in my code?

Comment: As this is a graduation project, I assume you have the precursor classes to understand the basics of program structure. What are the parameters of `CreateCorridorBetween`? Might that be a hint as to where its functionality fits within the bigger structure of the program?

Comment: Another clue is that `DrawCorridors` requires a list full of corridors. On the blog, you can see an example of where `DrawCorridors` is called. So the corridors have to be made some point before that!.

Answer (score 0):

Considering the parameters of `CreateCorridorBetween` are `SubDungeon left` and `SubDungeon right` you would want to call the method after you create the rooms. I assume you have read the blog that you linked to but as the writer states

> > ## Connect the rooms: create corridors between rooms
>
> Isolated rooms are not very useful, so we’ll add corridors between them. To do so, we’ll connect each leaf to its sibling. Then going up one level in the tree, we’ll repeat the process to connect parents sub-dungeons, until finally we connect the two initial sub-dungeons (see the stackexchange answer for illustrations).

This implies that there is more to this then a basic "just call it" solution.

Hope this helps and good luck on your project!